# Struts2: Showing and handling a form in one action (post back to the same action)

Tags: struts2

Coming from frameworks like Django and RoR I am used to show and handle forms from one action. (posting back to the action that shows the form) Is this possible in Struts2 as well? I'd like the following behavior:

1) "users/xyz/edit" gets called 
2) HTTP GET -> showing the form
3) HTTP POST -> form validation -> saving data and redirect or return to the form

All the examples I have looked at work with two actions which I dislike.

Is there any solution or do I have to accept the Struts2 way of doing it?

Comment: You absolutely should post back to the same action.

Comment: I don't know... If validation is being used, would there not need to be a check to see if none of the data has been filled out so no error messages are generated?

Comment: You can use the same action class with two methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the same Action class. Though its not as elegant as both those frameworks you mentioned since they encapsulate the REST principle at a framework level. Using the base Struts 2 framework, just add an actionType hidden parameter to your page and form, update it according to next expected action (display->validate->save->display).

Or alternatively you can use the REST plugin for Struts 2:

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html

Hope that helps.